# I hear people say this often time. Which is correct

Tags: grammaticality

"I will visit you today, come rain come shine" or "come rain come sun shine".

Comment: Incidentally, *sunshine* is written without a space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Come rain or shine* is the common usage for this sentence.

**Rain or shine:**
no matter whether it rains or the sun shines. Don't worry. I'll be there rain or shine. We'll hold the picnic—rain or shine.

Source: McGrow Hill Dict.